# Order by infos do not have approved or rejected yet

Tags: php, laravel

I have HR dashboard display all forms (The applicants form)

I want to display it order by pending forms

I wrote this code but it doesn't work

```php
public function index(){
    $pending = PersonalInfo::doesntHave('hraction')->first();
    $infos = PersonalInfo::orderBy($pending, 'desc')->latest()->simplePaginate();

    $rank = $infos->firstItem();
    return view('HR/HrEmployee',["infos",$infos,"rank"=>$rank]);
}
```

And this error appeared

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.`jpg","personlPhoto":"resources\/images\/$2y$10$XoxGRUQiFBZgroZfj0R5ef8LnSro...' at line 1 (SQL: select * from` personal_infos` order by ... limit 16 offset 0)

To be clear for you i have tow tables (personalInfos & Hractions)

prsonalInfos:

```
| id  | firstname | fathername | ...
```

Hractions:

```
| id | user_id | action | comment | personal_id | created_at |updated_at
```

Answer (score 1):

your variable `$pending` is a whole collection, you can not pass it as is, you need a column name there instead.

```
   $infos = PersonalInfo::orderBy('firstname', 'desc')->latest()->simplePaginate();
```

firstname is just an example, put the appropriate field of the table you want to order there.

So basically you don't need to use the same model 2 times, you can simply do:

```
$infos = PersonalInfo::doesntHave('hraction')->orderBy('firstname', 'desc')->latest()->simplePaginate();
```

This will return you all the data from `PersonalInfo` model without `hraction` relationship and use ordering + pagination on them in one step.

Comment: The first parameter of `orderBy` is the column name, i guess the column `John` does not exist

Comment: oups you are correct it's order, let me twist that.

Comment: I want return all data with hraction relationship and without hraction relationship
order by datat without hraction relationship

I mean the pending infos on the top of table

Answer (score 0):

`orderBy()`'s first argument needs to be a field in the database.
If you want to order them from latest to most recent you can use either the `id` field, or `created_at`.
Something like this:

```php
$infos = PersonalInfo::orderBy('id', 'desc')->latest()->simplePaginate();
$infos = PersonalInfo::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->latest()->simplePaginate();
```

in the end the Eloquent model queries are being transformed into plain SQL. So if you had that in mind, it will be much simpler to build the eloquent queries.